# How can I use VBA code to convert a .html file to an existing .xlsm file?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have software that generates a 2x 25,000 table of numbers in an .html format. My current process is opening the **.html**, saving as Excel workbook, etc.

The goal is to automate the process, import the data to Excel, and generate graphs and box charts. I have used macros to accomplish the latter but I am struggling with getting the .html data into the existing **.xlsm**.

I have found this code, from a helpful thread on Stack Overflow:

```
Sub Open_HTML_Save_XLSX()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Temp\Example.html"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Temp\Example.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End Sub
```

However, I'm not sure how to use it. I've been using custom made keyboard shortcuts to access my macros such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. I also don't know how to edit it to suit **.xlsm**.

Comment: If you're using Windows, I think the keystroke is `Alt` + `F11` to get to the VBA editor. You'll want to paste your sample code into there, probably within a module.  Or possibly within a sheet's "Load" method?

Comment: Bring up the VBE (Alt+F11), then paste the code in a new standard (.bas) module. You'll want to change `.xlsx` to `.xlsm`, and replace `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` with `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`... but, what's the use of saving as a macro-enabled workbook if there aren't any macros in it? An HTML file won't have macros to save. This looks like an X-Y problem, i.e. you need X but you're solving Y. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, thank you and you have a point. I was hoping to not only save the html as a excel workbook, but also into an existing .xlsm which would automate the process of analysing the data. That may or may not be possible. However, since my goal is to take 50 button clicks and reduce it to 10, the code I provided just might work for me. So, I have created a blank excel and a module in VBA and imputed the code. How do I run it? Within the VBA, I have tried the Run Sub/User Form, F5 and have successfully opened it as a .xlsx. How can I run this command without opening VBA?